# ViewController programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know what steps are needed once a fresh "Single view" project was created in xcode, in order to achieve:
1. a viewController that initializes without a NIB, but rather programmatically loads it's own controls in its view.
2. How to get that viewcontroller's view to `load` and call `viewDidLoad`?
3. make the view for that controller visible on the screen with all of the controls.

How do I go about this from this function:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLoadingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

I am trying to modify a new xcode project but all I get is a black screeen, viewDidLoad doesn't get called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your app delegate's application loading method.

In there, you would probably want to create an instance of your custom view controller and assign that as the rootViewController to your app delegate didFinishLoading. There should be a line like:

```
// app delegate .h file

#import "CustomViewController.h"

@interface
{
    ...
    CustomViewController *myCustomVC;
    ...
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CustomViewController *myCustomVC;


// app delegate .m file
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize myCustomVC;

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLoadingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    ...
    myCustomerVC = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];

    [self.window setRootViewController:myCustomVC]; 
    ...
}
```

Then inside your custom view controller's viewDidLoad method, you can do this as a test:

```
// custom view controller .m file
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[myViewController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view]; // if you want to add it in another viewcontroller

// For testing, set the background color to something other than white (default)

[myViewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

And off you go !

Comment: who is self as in self.view (line 3)?

Comment: The viewcontroller where you want to add the new view. In a new Single View project this would be in "ViewController.m", for example in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Is this way supposed to wake up viewDidLoad?

Comment: The viewDidLoad will fire on the myViewController object, if you want to do stuff in viewDidLoad you will need to subclass UIViewController and implement your own viewDidLoad logic. I strongly advice you take a look at various tutorials (ex. http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) or buy a good book about Beginning iOS development if you want to learn more about viewcontrollers and iOS development.

Comment: thanks, I sure will. I just posted an edit. I don't want to use the built in viewcontroller, but rather build my own

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a subclass of `UIViewController`, and setup your view hierarchy either in `loadView`, or `viewDidLoad` (depending on the level of customisation)

By subclassing `UIViewController` the loading method calls will be made for you so you don't have to worry about getting getting `viewDidLoad` etc.

To make it visible on the screen the simplest way is to set it as the `rootViewController` of the apps window

inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your app delegate

```
self.window.rootViewController = [[MyViewControllerSubclass alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];
    [self.window setRootViewController:homeVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Remove Main(storyboard reference) from Main interface of general Setting :
[image]

Add Launch Image :
And select iOS-7 and later in your left corner setting 
[image]